# Eliminar elemento de lista cuando checkbox esta unchecked con jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, lista, checkbox

Tengo unos items con checkbox que cuando se da check, se agrega el nombre del item a una lista a la derecha que funciona bien, pero cuando doy uncheck quiero que se elimine ese item del DOM... 
He estado intentando con **find() remove()** pero no funciona

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
    var product_name = $(this).data('name-display');
    var product_id = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         //AQUI AGREGO EL ITEM A LA LISTA
        $('.selected-items').append('<li id="'+ product_id +'">'+product_name+'</li>');
    } else {
         //AQUI ESTABA INTENTANDO ELIMINAR
        $('.selected-items').find('<li id="'+ $(this).attr("id") + '">'+product_name+'</li>').remove();
    }
});
```

y muestra este error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li id="product-one">Computadora</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el método `find()` debes pasar un "selector", en este caso con el ID, prueba lo siguiente:

```
$('.selected-items').find('#'+ $(this).attr("id")).remove();
```